# jQuery function to switch body class in an index

Tags: jquery, slider, slideshow

I have a list of N unique body classes, they all have a corresponding big background image on them. I'm trying to build what essentially boils down to a standard slider but instead of shifting through the li's in a target class, I'm switching body classes ".one, .two, .three, . four, .five, etc..." using forward and back arrow navigations.

Not really sure how to do this properly, would love some insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is simple solution, I hope that it will help you

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style>
            li.active { background-color: green;}
            .one { background-color: red;}
            .two { background-color: green;}
            .three { background-color: yellow;}
            .four {background-color: #black;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('body').attr('class',$('#senad').val());
                $('#senad').change(function(){
                   $('body').attr('class',$(this).val());
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="senad" size="10">
            <option value="one">One</option>
            <option value="two">Two</option>
            <option value="three">Three</option>
            <option value="four">Four</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

So what I have done, I have created select box with the options, you can add them as many as you want, and just put value of option to be your class name, that you want to assign to body.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at `jQuery` cycle plugin, this seems like a good fit for you.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/